# Reading From File and Miming a Database

Tags: python, file, parsing, file-io, dictionary

Here's what I am trying to do:
I've built a mini-system that allows for user registering & so on, but the system is very dependent on `db_parse()` and `user_exists()`, because that are the main two conditionals for the whole script to run.

Basically I am testing if an user exists with user_exists('username') which should return a "True" (It's a dict which has a value of either True/False).

So, here's the whole code to it (Please excuse the indendation:

```
class __system():
    def __init__(self):
        self.usernames = []
        self.passwords = []
        self.dbname = 'database.txt'
        self.privilege = [1,2,3]
        self.backupdb = 'backup.txt'

    def db_parse(self):
        d = {'username':[],
             'uid':[],
             'password':[],
             'pwdid':[]
             }
        with open(self.dbname,'r') as f:
            lines = ([line.rstrip() for line in f])
            f.flush()
            for x in xrange(0,len(lines)):
                if x%2==0:
                    d['username'].append(lines[x])
                    d['uid'].append(x) #-> number of line in the file
                if x%2==1:
                    d['password'].append(lines[x])
                    d['pwdid'].append(x)
            print lines
            f.close()
        return d

    def user_exists(self, username=''):
        d = {'exists': None,
             'uid': None
        }
        db = self.db_parse()
        ylen = len(db['username'])

        for y in range(0,ylen):
            if username == db['username'][y]:
                d['exists'] = True
                d['uid'] = db['uid'][y]

            else:
                d['exists'] = False
                d['uid'] = None
        return d

def main():
    obj = __system()
    print obj.user_exists('user1')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `'database.txt'` is looking like this:

```
user1<br>
203ad5ffa1d7c650ad681fdff3965cd2<br>
user2<br>
6e809cbda0732ac4845916a59016f954<br>
```

How can I say this...this sometimes work, this doesn't and I've done debugging for 10 hours straight (Yea, that's right.)
I can't seem to catch why it returns "False" and `"uid:0"` when the user clearly exists and then, 5 minutes later, only  re-pasting the code, it does work.

Comment: what exactly are you testing?

Comment: Sorry! I'm testing if the user exists. (It should be visible in the main function). Cheers!

Comment: I don't know how it is working as your user_exists method is still wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself for this, but the issue is here:

```
    for y in range(0,ylen):
        if username == db['username'][y]:
            d['exists'] = True
            d['uid'] = db['uid'][y]

        else:
            d['exists'] = False
            d['uid'] = None
    return d
```

If `username` matches the first user in the file, your for loop continues on to the second user in the file, which, of course, won't match. So it ends up returning False/None. You just need to add a `break` if a match is found:

```
    for y in range(0,ylen):
        if username == db['username'][y]:
            d['exists'] = True
            d['uid'] = db['uid'][y]
            break  # Add this
        else:
            d['exists'] = False
            d['uid'] = None
    return d
```

As an aside, you don't need to call `f.close()` if you're opening the file using `with open(...) as f`. The file will automatically close when you leave the `with` block. You should also use `for x, line in enumerate(lines):` instead of `for x in xrange(0, len(lines)):`